# How do I recover from git

Tags: git, github

I was working with my friend to a project,  after we fight he hide the project from me (I did a lot of commit), the problem is in the while I had to change my pc and I don't have the project anymore, is there a way to get at least my last commit back? Thanks who answer me

Comment: Did you use a remote repository? (Github or etc. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you provided the `GitHub`-tag for the question, I assume you have a remote repository on GitHub.
You just have to `git clone` the repository to your new computer and then you will have all the changes and commits available again. Only the changes where you don‘t have committed are missing.

To `git clone` you need the URL from the repository. To get this URL you have to log in to github or ask your friend

```
git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY
```

Comment: My friend put the repository private,  I was asking if there is a way to see my commit or history commit to get back the file

Comment: And what did your friend answer? Have you just only `git commit` or also `git push` your local changes? If only `git commit` the changes where lose, because only with `git push` you bring the changes from local to remote! And do you made the changes in a separat branch?

Comment: I did also git push but with my old pc that now I don't have anymore, there isn't a way to get back the history of what you did on git hub, even if he put the repository private from me?

Comment: Of course it is possible. You should have access to the private repository (but that should you already have since you pushed changes). So you'll need to log into github, navigate to that repository, and then copy the `git clone` command and run it on the command line or in a Git GUI-Tool.